# How to minimize “Recommended for You” section title when start office app by code

Tags: excel, ms-word, powerpoint, ms-office

I start office app by running cmd in code and want to minimize “Recommended for You” section title by default.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/recommended-files-in-office-232c8322-1060-4453-bd69-a4770efe731e

If user choose to minimize this section by clicking on the arrow to the left of the “Recommended for You” section title, it will be minimized at next time.

Where does Office app save this setting value?